# Show as Html on vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i have json file for translate ( en.json ) and this line :

```
{ 
  "cancel order": "Hi, How can i <b> Cancel </b> ?",
}


      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-content-center mb-4">
    <span class="description col-sm-11 col-md-7 col-lg-10">
    
    {{ $t('cancel order') }}
  
    </span>
  </div>
```

now my result is  " Hi, How can i  **Cancel**  "

The problem is that the html code does not apply like this  code and the tags are displayed exactly without being applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `v-html` directive to rander raw html.

```js
const htmlcontent = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
```

```html
<span v-html="htmlcontent">
</span>
```

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<div v-html="$t('cancel order')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**One observation :** Using camelCase in property names consider as a best practice. Hence, use `cancel order` instead of `cancel order`.

To render your translation as an HTML message and not a static string. You can use `v-html`.

Template **:**

```
<span class="description col-sm-11 col-md-7 col-lg-10" v-html="$t('cancelOrder')"></span>
```